# How to split a column into multiple columns data

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have list of TCGA Tumor sample ids as follows:

```
SAMPLE_ID
TCGA.13.1407.01A.01R.1565.13
TCGA.24.2254.01A.01R.1568.13
TCGA.24.0982.01A.01R.1565.13
TCGA.24.1847.01A.01R.1566.13
TCGA.24.2289.01A.01R.1568.13
TCGA.31.1959.01A.01R.1568.13
```

I want to split the sample id into: Project, TSS, Participant, Sample, Vial, Portion, Analyte, Plate, Center
For example for first row it will be :

```
SAMPLE_ID                       Project TSS Participant Sample  Vial    Portion Analyte Plate   Center
TCGA.13.1407.01A.01R.1565.13    TCGA    13  1407        01      A       01      R       0182    13
```

I tried as below:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df = data.frame(SAMPLE_ID = c("TCGA.13.1407.01A.01R.1565.13", "TCGA.24.2254.01A.01R.1568.13", "TCGA.24.0982.01A.01R.1565.13",
                                "TCGA.24.1847.01A.01R.1566.13", "TCGA.24.2289.01A.01R.1568.13", "TCGA.31.1959.01A.01R.1568.13"))
```

then,

```
result = data %>% separate(SAMPLE_ID,
                            into = c("Project", "TSS", "Participant", "Sample", "Vial",
                                     "Portion", "Analyte", "Plate", "Center"),
                            sep = "\\.")
```

but it gave me:

```
Project TSS Participant Sample  Vial    Portion Analyte Plate   Center
<chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>
TCGA    13  1407    01A 01R 1565    13  NA  NA
TCGA    24  2254    01A 01R 1568    13  NA  NA
TCGA    24  0982    01A 01R 1565    13  NA  NA
TCGA    24  1847    01A 01R 1566    13  NA  NA
TCGA    24  2289    01A 01R 1568    13  NA  NA
TCGA    31  1959    01A 01R 1568    13  NA  NA
```

Comment: Use `read.fwf` from pkg:foreign

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `separate` from `tidyr` like @jynxmaze but with other separator `sep = "\\.|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)"` and using `extra` and `remove` argument:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  separate(SAMPLE_ID, 
           into = c("Project", "TSS", "Participant", "Sample", "Vial", "Portion", "Analyte", "Plate", "Center"),
           sep = "\\.|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)", extra = "merge", remove = FALSE)
```

```
    SAMPLE_ID Project TSS Participant Sample Vial Portion Analyte Plate Center
1 TCGA.13.1407.01A.01R.1565.13    TCGA  13        1407     01    A      01       R  1565     13
2 TCGA.24.2254.01A.01R.1568.13    TCGA  24        2254     01    A      01       R  1568     13
3 TCGA.24.0982.01A.01R.1565.13    TCGA  24        0982     01    A      01       R  1565     13
4 TCGA.24.1847.01A.01R.1566.13    TCGA  24        1847     01    A      01       R  1566     13
5 TCGA.24.2289.01A.01R.1568.13    TCGA  24        2289     01    A      01       R  1568     13
6 TCGA.31.1959.01A.01R.1568.13    TCGA  31        1959     01    A      01       R  1568     13
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `read.fwf` (as *@IRTFM* suggests) is probably a good solution. First we could remove the periods and save to a `tempfile`.

```
> write.table(as.matrix(dat$SAMPLE_ID |> gsub('\\.', '', x=_)), tmp <- tempfile(),
+             col.names=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
> 
> read.fwf(tmp, widths=c(4, 2, 4, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2), header=FALSE, 
+          col.names=c("Project", "TSS", "Participant", "Sample", "Vial",
+                      "Portion", "Analyte", "Plate", "Center"))
  Project TSS Participant Sample Vial Portion Analyte Plate Center
1    TCGA  13        1407      1    A       1       R  1565     13
2    TCGA  24        2254      1    A       1       R  1568     13
3    TCGA  24         982      1    A       1       R  1565     13
4    TCGA  24        1847      1    A       1       R  1566     13
5    TCGA  24        2289      1    A       1       R  1568     13
6    TCGA  31        1959      1    A       1       R  1568     13
```

You probably can read in the file directly and skip the `write.table` step.

You can add some cleaning stuff if you depend on character columns and leading zeroes.

```
> read.fwf(tmp, widths=c(4, 2, 4, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2), header=FALSE, 
+          col.names=c("Project", "TSS", "Participant", "Sample", "Vial",
+                      "Portion", "Analyte", "Plate", "Center")) |>
+   transform(TSS=sprintf('%02d', TSS), 
+             Participant=sprintf('%04d', Participant), 
+             Sample=sprintf('%02d', Sample),
+             Portion=sprintf('%02d', Portion),
+             Plate=as.character(Plate),
+             Center=as.character(Center))
  Project TSS Participant Sample Vial Portion Analyte Plate Center
1    TCGA  13        1407     01    A      01       R  1565     13
2    TCGA  24        2254     01    A      01       R  1568     13
3    TCGA  24        0982     01    A      01       R  1565     13
4    TCGA  24        1847     01    A      01       R  1566     13
5    TCGA  24        2289     01    A      01       R  1568     13
6    TCGA  31        1959     01    A      01       R  1568     13


> unlink(tmp) ## unlink if no longer needed
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(dat)
structure(list(SAMPLE_ID = c("TCGA.13.1407.01A.01R.1565.13", 
"TCGA.24.2254.01A.01R.1568.13", "TCGA.24.0982.01A.01R.1565.13", 
"TCGA.24.1847.01A.01R.1566.13", "TCGA.24.2289.01A.01R.1568.13", 
"TCGA.31.1959.01A.01R.1568.13")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: The output is wrong. See my expected output

Comment: @nicholaspooran See updated answer. To improve on, how do you currently read in your file?

Answer (score 4):

Try `read.table` with a bit string annotations using `gsub`

```
setNames(
  read.table(text = gsub("(\\d)([^0-9.])", "\\1.\\2", df$SAMPLE_ID), sep = "."),
  c(
    "Project", "TSS", "Participant", "Sample", "Vial",
    "Portion", "Analyte", "Plate", "Center"
  )
)
```

which should give

```
  Project TSS Participant Sample Vial Portion Analyte Plate Center
1    TCGA  13        1407      1    A       1       R  1565     13
2    TCGA  24        2254      1    A       1       R  1568     13
3    TCGA  24         982      1    A       1       R  1565     13
4    TCGA  24        1847      1    A       1       R  1566     13
5    TCGA  24        2289      1    A       1       R  1568     13
6    TCGA  31        1959      1    A       1       R  1568     13
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is with `extract`:

The `regex` part looks much more complicated than it is: it just recycles, and adapts to contingencies of the string, the same nucleus, i.e., `([^.]+)`, which is a capture group that matches anything one or more times, that is **not** a `\\.`:

```
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  extract(SAMPLE_ID,
          into = c("Project", "TSS", "Participant", "Sample", "Vial",
                    "Portion", "Analyte", "Plate", "Center"),
          regex = "([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)\\.([^.]{2})([^.])\\.([^.]{2})([^.])\\.([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)"
          )
  Project TSS Participant Sample Vial Portion Analyte Plate Center
1    TCGA  13        1407     01    A      01       R  1565     13
2    TCGA  24        2254     01    A      01       R  1568     13
3    TCGA  24        0982     01    A      01       R  1565     13
4    TCGA  24        1847     01    A      01       R  1566     13
5    TCGA  24        2289     01    A      01       R  1568     13
6    TCGA  31        1959     01    A      01       R  1568     13
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in two steps:

```
# Split the SAMPLE_ID into columns
df = data %>% separate(SAMPLE_ID,
                       into = c("Project", "TSS", "Participant", "Sample", "Portion", "Plate", "Center"),
                       sep = "\\.")
```

then,

```
# Add new columns
df1 <- df %>% mutate(Patient_ID = paste(Project,'.',TSS,'.',Participant, sep = ""),
                     Vial = substr(Sample, 3, 3),
                     Analyte = substr(Portion, 3, 3))

# Reorder the columns
df1 <- df1 %>% select(Patient_ID, Project, TSS, Participant, Sample, Vial, Portion, Analyte, Plate, Center)
df1
```